# Inno Setup files owned by Administrator

Tags: inno-setup

My setup project performs a UAC check because it uses `regserver`.  This is OK (and in fact necessary); however it makes *all* of the installed files be owned by `Administrator` , and not by the user that originally ran the installer.

This means that the user that ran the installer cannot edit any of the configuration files that are part of my installation.

I don't want to set permission on the files to be writable by `Everyone`; they just need to be writable by the user that ran the installation.

Does Inno Setup have any way of assigning ownership of certain files (or all of the files) to the user that ran the self-installing executable?

I am not using the line `PrivilegesRequired=admin` although it seems makes no difference whether or not that line is active. (Presumably because `regserver` implies this).

Comment: I believe that `PrivilegesRequired=admin` is the `Default` for Inno. Try to use `poweruser` or other parameter. You can also separate the `installation` (file copying)) from the `regserver` by e.g. compiling it into separate executable and triggering it at the end of the installation. `[Setup]: PrivilegesRequired Valid values:
 none, poweruser, admin, or lowest  
Default value:
 admin`

Comment: Doing "poweruser" made no difference (I think that doesn't exist in Win 7 or later anyway). The separate-executable plan might work tho